# How can I get first value from second element in this JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, return-value

I have JSON with 2 collection FailedCount and SucceededCount.

```js
{
 "FailedCount": [{
    "FailedCount_DATE_CURRENT_CHECK": "2016-11-30 10:40:09.0",
    "FailedCount_DATE__CURRENT__CHECK": "10:40:09",
    "FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE": 0
  }, {
    "FailedCount_DATE_CURRENT_CHECK": "2016-11-30 10:45:09.0",
    "FailedCount_DATE__CURRENT__CHECK": "10:45:09",
    "FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE": 0
  }, {
    "FailedCount_DATE_CURRENT_CHECK": "2016-11-30 10:50:09.0",
    "FailedCount_DATE__CURRENT__CHECK": "10:50:09",
    "FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE": 1
  }],
  "SucceededCount": [{
    "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE": 555
  }, {
    "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE": 547
  }, {
    "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE": 339
  }]
}
```

How get first value `SucceededCount`?

I tried:

```js
jsonObj.SucceededCount[1];
```

But the result is not good: `[object Object]`.

Comment: use jsonObj.SucceededCount[1].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE

Comment: `obj.SucceededCount[0]["SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE"]`

Comment: the **first** would be index 0, not 1, but having said that, `[object Object]` is how an Object is shown as a string

Comment: ok, thanks, working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
jsonObj.SucceededCount[0].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take the property `SucceededCount` of your object. You now have an array. Take the fist object of this array `SucceededCount[0]` and then select the property you need `SucceededCount[0].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE`

```js
var obj = {
  "FailedCount": [{
    "FailedCount_DATE_CURRENT_CHECK": "2016-11-30 10:40:09.0",
    "FailedCount_DATE__CURRENT__CHECK": "10:40:09",
    "FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE": 0
  }, {
    "FailedCount_DATE_CURRENT_CHECK": "2016-11-30 10:45:09.0",
    "FailedCount_DATE__CURRENT__CHECK": "10:45:09",
    "FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE": 0
  }, {
    "FailedCount_DATE_CURRENT_CHECK": "2016-11-30 10:50:09.0",
    "FailedCount_DATE__CURRENT__CHECK": "10:50:09",
    "FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE": 1
  }],
  "SucceededCount": [{
    "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE": 555
  }, {
    "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE": 547
  }, {
    "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE": 339
  }]
};

console.log(obj.SucceededCount[0].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE);
```